# Сравнение структур массивов

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Как сравнить структуры двух массивов?

Функция должна проходить следующие тесты:

```
//Должен вернуть true
[1, 1, 1].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2]) 
[1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
[1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]])
[[[], []]].hasSameStructure([[[], []]])

//Должен вернуть false
[1, 1, 1].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [2]])
[1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2])
[1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]])
[[[], []]].hasSameStructure([[1, 1]])
```

Каркас функции:

```
Array.prototype.hasSameStructure = function (array) { /*код*/ };
```

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko все для вас

Comment: Отклонил предложенную вами [правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/271336). Пожалуйста, не злоупотребляйте [внутристрочным форматированием](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/213987). Увы, очень часто сообщения прямо разукрашивают не к месту, думая, что так будет лучше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмем за предположение, что в массиве только цифры и другие массивы

```js
Array.prototype.hasSameStructure = function (b) {
  // не буду здесь писать проверку, на то что входные данные это массивы
  const a = this;
  if(a.length !== b.length) return false;
  
  const isArray = Array.isArray;
  const aLength = a.length;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < aLength; i++) {
    const aValue = a[i];
    const bValue = b[i];
    
    if(isArray(aValue) !== isArray(bValue)) {
      return false;
    }
    
    if(isArray(aValue) && isArray(bValue)) {
      const result = aValue.hasSameStructure(bValue);
      
      if(!result) return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}


//Должен вернуть true
console.log([1, 1, 1]
  .hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
  .hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]
  .hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]));
console.log([[[], []]]
  .hasSameStructure([[[], []]]));

//Должен вернуть false
console.log([1, 1, 1]
  .hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [2]]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
  .hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]
  .hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]));
console.log([[[], []]]
  .hasSameStructure([[1, 1]]));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я хотел что-то подобное моему второму решению

Comment: @NikitaSmith ну и зачем эта нечитаемая каша в одну строчку? Вы через пол года сможете быстро понять, что это код делает-то

Comment: ну честно говоря без проблем код читается, даже если в одну строчку)

Comment: @NikitaSmith, вы, наерное, не слышал о `Code Style`, длина строки очень большая ( скорее даже больше 120 символов ), за раз ее глазами не увидеть. Да и в данном случае вертикально информация воспринимается лучше. Код в одну строчку больше похож на тот, что уже прошел `uglify` и просто оптимизирован

Answer (score 0):

### Решение

В данный момент использую следующую функцию:

```js
Array.prototype.hasSameStructure = function (array) {
    if (!Array.isArray(array) || this.length != array.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
        if (Array.isArray(this[i])) {
            if (!this[i].hasSameStructure(array[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
};

//Должен вернуть true
console.log([1, 1, 1].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]));
console.log([[[], []]].hasSameStructure([[[], []]]))

// //Должен вернуть false
console.log([1, 1, 1].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [2]]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]));
console.log([[[], []]].hasSameStructure([[1, 1]]));
```

Функция проходит все тесты. Но хотелось бы реализовать ее под более "свежий" стандарт, и использовать маленькую стрелочную функцию.

### Короткое рекурсивное решение

```js
Array.prototype.hasSameStructure = function (array) {
    return this.length == array.length && this.every((element, index) => Array.isArray(element) == Array.isArray(array[index]) && (!Array.isArray(element) || element.hasSameStructure(array[index])));
};

//Должен вернуть true
console.log([1, 1, 1].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]));
console.log([[[], []]].hasSameStructure([[[], []]]))

// //Должен вернуть false
console.log([1, 1, 1].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [2]]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2]));
console.log([1, 1, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]].hasSameStructure([2, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]));
console.log([[[], []]].hasSameStructure([[1, 1]]));
console.log([1, [1]].hasSameStructure([2, 2]));
```

Comment: `console.log([1, 1].hasSameStructure([2, [2]]));` не работает

Comment: @teran Точно, второй вариант не работает! `console.log([1, [1, [2]]].hasSameStructure([2, [2, 3]]))` работает. C первой вложенностью проблема.

Comment: @teran исправил